# Squid Cache control based on HTTP Replies

Tags: squid

Is there any way to write squid ACLs about how long you cache a HTTP reply based on the HTTP Reply Code you receive. I specifically want to exclude 404, 403, 500, and 503 error codes from being cached, so I can confirm they have been resolved when working on a site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [`negative_ttl`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/negative_ttl/) directive in your squid.conf.